# ListView Item doesnt change Visual in Background

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-styles

I'm trying to change my ListView item's visual but it doesn't change, I'm using this tutorial http://ryanharter.com/blog/2013/01/31/how-to-make-an-android-card-list/ but my listview item doesn't change.

I made the bg_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:dither="true">

            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>

            <solid android:color="#ccc" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:dither="true">

            <corners android:radius="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <padding android:bottom="8dp"
                android:left="8dp"
                android:right="8dp"
                android:top="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and put in my ListView but this doesn't change the visual, was thus:

[image]

My listview is:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_card"
    />
```

Please if someone has a suggestion, I don't know how to deal with this issue.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the background to the listItem layout, not to the listview.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/bg_card"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Same result, appear some the buttom bar

Comment: If you are using a nested viewgroups, then try it in them.